# Input from user and append into mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I would like to read user input and insert it into a mysql statement and thereby execute it.

```
public class DropTable {
    static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    Connection connection = null;
    String input;
    public void deleteColumns(){
       try {

             connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,"jezza", "10");
             Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
             Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);     
             System.out.println("Enter the value to delete");
             input = value.nextLine();
             stmt.executeUpdate("delete from books where LastName = "+value.toString() );
            }// end try
            catch (SQLException ex) {
              System.out.println("Error "+ex.toString());
               System.out.println("dropTable");
               System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
                System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
                System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            } // end catch 
       } //end deleteColumns
}
```

The scanner is unable to take the user input and insert it into the query. Following is the error I got. According to the error its the query statement that is generating the problem. How may I go about this?

```
> Error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false' at line 1
dropTable
SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false' at line 1
SQLState: 42000
VendorError: 1064
```

Comment: You're calling `toString()` on a `Scanner` object. You're not actually passing any user input to the query. Also, don't create your query dynamically. Use a `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
input = value.nextLine();
stmt.executeUpdate("delete from books where LastName = "+value.toString() );
```

should be

```
input = value.nextLine();
stmt.executeUpdate("delete from books where LastName = " + input );
```

But also don't do it this way. You're setting yourself up for SQL injection. Use a `PreparedStatement`. [Here's a tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)